# UI control for entering multiple string values

Tags: gui-design, silverlight

Is there a good UI control to fulfil the following requirement: "A user must be able to enter one or many 4 digit alpha numeric codes for each ID restricted."
This would need to be a cell template in a Silverlight grid of multiple rows. I cannot think of anything other than a pop-up with a form to add/remove these IDs and show them as a comma-separated string in a read-only textbox in a grid itself.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something similar to this:

[image]

After each 4 alphanumeric codes a group is made (which can be discarded).

Comment: yes, this is great. is there an example implementation somewhere?

Comment: Stack Exchange tags? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags

Comment: it's commonly used for tags, yes.